# Will one MongoDB deep index supported all queries up to that depth?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

The queries for one of the larger tables in our system take one of the three forms:

1. A
2. A+B+C
3. A+B+C+D+E

Will one index that is based on indexing A,B,C,D,E together (and in that order, which is the order the queries are built) be sufficient for all three queries or will the system require a second index, for A, and a third, for A+B+C.

If I wanted to confirm this, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes are created to access data fast which make the queries run fast. Indexes can be created on single or multiple fields; an index on multiple fields is called as a **compound index**.

A collection's document has fields `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `X`, `Y` and `Z`. There are multiple queries on this collection and they use some sub set of the fields as the query's filter criteria. As in the question, the queries are on the fields:

```
A
A, B
A, B, C
A, B, C, D
```

In such cases, one index can be built to accommodate all the queries's needs. It will be a compound index with all the fields: A, B, C and D. For example, create the index:

`db.collection.createIndex( { A: 1, B: 1, C: 1, D: 1 } )`. Note the value `1` which specifies the index as *ascending*, can be `-1` specifying *descending* .

Note the order of the fields specified in the index definition matters. The queries can be any of the following (for, example), and all these use the same index effectively.

```
db.collection.find( { A: "some value" } )
db.collection.find( { A: "some value", B: 24 } )
db.collection.find( { A: "some value", B: 24, C: ISODate("2020-02-24" } )
db.collection.find( { A: "some value", B: 24, C: ISODate("2020-02-24" }, D: "another value" )
```

Note the fields used in the query matters for the index to be used. A query on the `C` alone *or* `B` and `D` together alone will not use the index. The queries fields must be a sub-set of the fields starting from the left-most field(s) (i.e., `A`, or `A+B`, etc.), and these are called as [Index Prefixes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/index.html#prefixes).

Note the order of the fields specified within the query do *not* matter for the indexes to be applied; also, the results will be the same too. The following query has same effect as that of the previous one with the same fields:

```
db.collection.find( { C: ISODate("2020-02-24" }, A: "some value", D: "another value", B: 24 )
```

An advantage of using a single compound index to apply it on multiple queries in that it reduces the maintenance of indexes, and resources like memory and disk space for the index. Also, note that index prefixes can be applied on sort operations.

*Query Plan:*

Now, that we have the theory that we can use Index Prefixes, how do we verify this actually works? The way is to generate a query plan on the queries that use the compound index and verify the index usage. A query plan is generated with the `explain` method applied on the collection, [db.collection.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html).

For example, `db.colection.explain().find( { A: "some value" } )` generates an [Explain Output](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/index.html), where you can see the details about the query, the index usage, etc. You should notice a stage called as IXSCAN, which indicates scanning of the index keys.